# Having trouble verifying a solution for a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Verify that $x=(t+1)e^{2t}$ is a solution for

$$x = 2x+e^{2t},\ \ x(0)=1$$

My approach so far is.

$$x' =2x+e^{2t}$$
$$dx/dt = 2x+e^{2t}$$

$$\int(dx-2x) =\int e^{2t}dt + C$$
$$-x^2 = e^{2t}/2 + C$$

Not sure if this is the right approach or what to do from here.

Comment: Much easier is to derivate the given solution and check if the differential equation is valid if the solution is inserted.

Comment: The equation should start with $x '$

Comment: My mistake with that x'. 

my have made a arithmetic error but here's what i get doing that.

x=(t+1)e^(2t)
x' = ((2t+1)e^(2t))/4+ C
((2t+1)e^(2t))/4 = 2x+e^(2t)

(2t+1)e^(2t) = (2x+e^(2t))(4)
(2t+1)e^(2t) = 8x+4e^(2t)
(2t+1)e^(2t) - 4e^(2t) = 8x 

((2t+1)e^2t - 4e^(2t))/8=x

so it's not a solution.

Comment: @uniquesolution edit question My approach so far is.

$$x' =2x+e^{2t}$$
$$dx/dt = 2x+e^{2t}$$

$$\int-2xdx =\int e^{2t}dt + C$$
$$-x^2 = e^2(t)/2 + C$$

Not sure if this is the right approach or what to do from here.

Comment: It seems the expression $\displaystyle\int(dx - 2x)$ does not cause you any pain. The expression $\displaystyle\int dx$ is sometimes thought of a a sum of infinitely many infinitely small quantities called $dx$, but then what is $-2x$?  If you have $$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 2x + e^{2t}$$ that can become $$dx = 2x\,dt + e^{2t}\,dt,$$ but that doesn't lend itself to separation of variables.  Other methods are needed here. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

$$x(t)=(t+1)(e^{2t})$$

$$x'(t)=e^{2t}+(2t+2)e^{2t}=2(t+1)e^{2t}+e^{2t}=2x(t)+e^{2t}$$

$$x(0)=1\times e^{0}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

To verify that $x=(t+1)e^{2t}$ is a solution to 
$$x'=2x+e^{2t},\hspace{10mm}x(0)=1$$
you don't need to do any integration. All you have to do is verify the initial condition and that the two sides of the differential equation are the same:

Verifying $x(0)=0$:
$$x(0)=(0+1)e^{2(0)}=e^0=1$$

Calculation of $x'$:
$$x'=\frac{d}{dt}\left[(t+1)e^{2t}\right]=\frac{d}{dt}\left[te^{2t}+e^{2t}\right]=2te^{2t}+e^{2t}+2e^{2t}=2te^{2t}+3e^{2t}$$

Calculation of $2x+e^{2t}$:
$$2x+e^{2t}=2(t+1)e^{2t}+e^{2t}=2te^{2t}+2e^{2t}+e^{2t}=2te^{2t}+3e^{2t}$$

Since both sides are the same, we have verified that $x=(t+1)e^{2t}$ is a solution to the given differential equation.